# Using a dataframe in a list of dataframes as a function argument in R and calling it by its name

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

Hey so I recently asked a question that I worded pretty poorly so I wanted to ask again with a better example. Let's say I have a list of dataframes like so:

```
first<- data.frame(b = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
           levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
           x = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
           z = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
second<- data.frame(b = factor(c("Med", "Med", "Low", "Low"), 
           levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
           x = c("c", "B", "C", "D"), y = c(3, 2, 6, 5),
           z = c(1, 11, 4, 3))

c<- list(first,second)
```

I then would go on to name the data frames in the list:

```
names(c)<- c("first","second")
```

Now let's say I wanted to make a function to take the mean of a column in a subset of the data frame "second". My only argument would be what column I wanted to take the mean of:

```
test<- function(arg1){
  poop<- subset(c$second, c$second$b=="Med")
  pee<- mean(poop[,arg1])
  return(pee)
}
```

If I test this function out it works fine:

```
test("y")
[1] 2.5
```

Now the issue I'm having is that I want to make the data frame in the list of data frames an argument in the function. It would change to this:

```
test<- function(arg0, arg1){
  poop<- subset(c$arg0, c$arg0$b=="Med")
  pee<- mean(poop[,arg1])
  return(pee)
}
```

And if I run the same code:

```
test("second","y")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(poop[, arg1]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

When I would want to get 2.5 again. I would want to call the data frame by its name in the list and not by any assigned element number. Thanks!

Comment: It is not recommended to use `$` inside a function.  Use `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `[`

```
test<- function(arg1, arg2){
   poop <- subset(c[[arg1]], b=='Med')
   mean(poop[[arg2]])
}

test("second", "y")
#[1] 2.5
```

Or if we need to pass arguments unquoted

```
test<- function(arg1, arg2){
   Call <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
   nm1 <- sapply(Call, deparse)
  mean(subset(c[[nm1[1]]], b=="Med")[[nm1[2]]])
}

test(second, y)
#[1] 2.5
```